# What's wrong with this Apache mod_rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to write some redirects for an Apache site, but my `mod_rewrite` skills are rusty. What's wrong with this rule?

```
RewriteRule ^/en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I expect it to redirect `http://example.com/en/whatevs.html` to `http://example.com/whatevs.html`, but it does not seem to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

You were close. It's hard in rewrite to remember when to use the starting / and when not to. I put in the rewriteengine on in case it had slipped your mind to include that.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/.*$
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note which has the slash and which does not.

And there's some subtle differences also depending on if your rules are in httpd.conf files or in .htaccess files, but I forget the exact differences.

Comment: Looks like the preceding slash is required in `VirtualHost` context and not in `Directory` and `htaccess` context.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, though I'm always reluctant to state that categorically since I tend to mix them up. I could just check my local configs of course, since I run all my local dev sites with virtualhosts, but tend to use htaccess for the live versions.